# PyTorch LSTM dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to teach my first LSTM with numeric sequence data to predict a singular value.

My training set is a numpy matrix shape=207x7 where each input vector has 7 features.
I am not sure how to setup and train my LSTM properly. I have CNN experience, but now first LSTM.

```
class LSTM_NN(nn.Module):
"""
Stores the network format
"""
def __init__(self, input_size=7, hidden_layer_size=100, output_size=1):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self._hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size
    self._lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_layer_size)
    self._hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(1, 1, self._hidden_layer_size),
                         torch.zeros(1, 1, self._hidden_layer_size))
    self._linear = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_size, output_size)

def forward(self, input_data):
    """
    Forward propagation
    """

    lstm_out, self._hidden_cell = self._lstm(
        torch.tensor(np.expand_dims(input_data, 0)),
        self._hidden_cell) 

training_data.shape
# (200, 7)
model = LSTM_NN(input_size=training_data.shape[1])
model.forward(training_data)
```

But I get this error:

```
Expected hidden[0] size (1, 200, 100), got (1, 1, 100)
  File "train_lstm.py", line 44, in forward
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input has size *[batch_size, seq_len, num_features] = [1, 200, 7]*. The LSTM on the other hand, expects the input to have size *[seq_len, batch_size, num_features]* (as described in [`nn.LSTM` - Inputs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM)).

You can either change the dimensions of your input, or you can set `batch_first=True` when creating the LSTM, if you prefer having batch size as the first dimension, in which case *batch_size* and *seq_len* are swapped and your current input size would be the expected one.

```py
self._lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_layer_size, batch_first=True)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what is a batch in time series training exactly?

Comment: You need multiple sequences for the model to learn properly. If you only have a single time series, you can create smaller series, e.g. with 100 time steps, so you would ask the model "Given time steps 1-100, what will the value be at time step 101?" You know the real value for step 101, so the model can learn from it. Then you can continue  but predict step 102 (given steps 2-101) and so on. That creates a lot of smaller sequences, you can even vary the sequence length, therefore you have multiple training samples, which can be batched to predict at the same time, while being independent.